# Camera info problem when trying to see topic in rqt

Tags: ros2, camera, rqt, camera-info

I am executing a camera_info topic with as this:

```
info1.header.stamp = msg1.header.stamp;
info1.header.frame_id = msg1.header.frame_id;
info1.width= 1280;
info1.height= 720;
info1.distortion_model= "plumb_bob";
info1.d= {-0.054569, 0.159222, -0.002236, 0.000731, 0.000000};
info1.k= {1154.22921,    0.     ,  645.10033,
        0.     , 1153.73786,  329.85776,
        0.     ,    0.     ,    1.     };
info1.r= {0.99963545, -0.01601458, -0.02173693,
      0.01595082,  0.99986796, -0.00310364,
      0.02178376,  0.00275579,  0.99975891};
info1.p= { 1240.59511,    0.     ,  689.01401,    0.     ,
        0.     , 1240.59511,  324.13377,    0.     ,
        0.     ,    0.     ,    1.     ,    0.     };
info1.binning_x= 0;
info1.binning_y= 0;
info1.roi.x_offset= 0;
info1.roi.y_offset= 0;
info1.roi.height= 0;
info1.roi.width= 0;
info1.roi.do_rectify= false;
```

When I do `ros2 topic echo` it works fine and shows me the correct parameters:

```
    header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1700244891
    nanosec: 954672831
  frame_id: camera_frame
height: 720
width: 1280
distortion_model: plumb_bob
d:
- -0.054569
- 0.159222
- -0.002236
- 0.000731
- 0.0
k:
- 1154.22921
- 0.0
- 645.10033
- 0.0
- 1153.73786
- 329.85776
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
r:
- 0.99963545
- -0.01601458
- -0.02173693
- 0.01595082
- 0.99986796
- -0.00310364
- 0.02178376
- 0.00275579
- 0.99975891
p:
- 1240.59511
- 0.0
- 689.01401
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1240.59511
- 324.13377
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi:
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: false
---
```

but when I try to see the topic in rqt I get these messages which I don't know what are they:

```
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rqt_topic/topic_widget.py", line 473, in __lt__
    return lhs < rhs
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (12,) 
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
TypeError: invalid result from TreeWidgetItem2.__lt__(), a 'bool' is expected not 'numpy.ndarray'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rqt_topic/topic_widget.py", line 473, in __lt__
    return lhs < rhs
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (9,) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rqt_topic/topic_widget.py", line 473, in __lt__
    return lhs < rhs
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?